# Find the Last Modified Date of a File in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

How can I find the last modified date of a file in cocoa?

Answer (score 6):

Check out *NSFileManager*'s

```
- (NSDictionary *)fileAttributesAtPath:(NSString *)path traverseLink:(BOOL)flag
```

the key you're interested in is NSFileModificationDate.

Comment: This is deprecated in 10.5, instead use
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error

Answer (score 5):

Just to update the code:

```
NSString * path = ... your path here ...
NSDate * fileLastModifiedDate = nil;

NSError * error = nil;
NSDictionary * attrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
if (attrs && !error)
{
    fileLastModifiedDate = [attrs fileModificationDate];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this answer here since this was the first result when I searched for how to do this, but if you're using swift you might like this extension:

```
extension NSFileManager {

    func modificationDateForFileAtPath(path:String) -> NSDate? {
        guard let attributes = try? self.attributesOfItemAtPath(path) else { return nil }
        return attributes[NSFileModificationDate] as? NSDate
    }

    func creationDateForFileAtPath(path:String) -> NSDate? {
        guard let attributes = try? self.attributesOfItemAtPath(path) else { return nil }
        return attributes[NSFileCreationDate] as? NSDate
    }


}
```